# C++ SIMD: Store uint64_t value after bitwise and operation

Tags: c++, c++11, sse, simd

I am trying to do a bitwise `&` between elements of two arrays of `uint64_t` integers and then store the result in another array. This is my program:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <chrono>


int main()
{

  uint64_t data[200];
  uint64_t data2[200];
  uint64_t data3[200];
  __m128i* ptr = (__m128i*) data;
  __m128i* ptr2 = (__m128i*) data2;
  uint64_t* ptr3 = data3;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i, ++ptr, ++ptr2, ptr3 += 2)
    _mm_store_ps(ptr3, _mm_and_si128(*ptr, *ptr2));

}
```

However, I get this error:

```
test.cpp:17:50: error: cannot convert ‘uint64_t* {aka long unsigned int*}’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void _mm_store_ps(float*, __m128)’
     _mm_store_ps(ptr3, _mm_and_si128(*ptr, *ptr2));
```

For some reason, the compiler thinks I'm copying to an array of floats. Is it possible to do what I am trying to do with arrays of `uint64_t`?

Comment: note: this violates the strict aliasing rule; compile with `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

Comment: @M.M I compiled like this `gcc -std=c++11 -fno-strict-aliasing test.cpp -o test` and I got no warning, how did you compile?

Comment: @M.M if you can give a "safer" and better answer, I will you accept your answer

Comment: @M.M also other people can benefit from your insight

Comment: I didn't compile and I don't have an answer to post. Which is why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @M.M The SSE vector types are declared `__may_alias__`. So it should be okay to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_mm_store_si128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_store_si128&expand=5158).

First change pointer `ptr3` to

```
  __m128i* ptr3 = (__m128i*) data3;
```

and then

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i, ++ptr, ++ptr2, ++ptr3)
    _mm_store_si128(ptr3, _mm_and_si128(*ptr, *ptr2));
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks angry pusheen!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the floating point operation [`_mm_store_ps`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_store_ps&expand=5158,5150) although you actually want to store integers. So either use [`_mm_store_si128`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_store_si128&expand=5158) or cast the result back to `uint64_t`.

You should also make sure to align the arrays to 16 byte, so aligned load/store operations can be used which will be faster.

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
  __declspec(align(16)) uint64_t data[200];
  __declspec(align(16)) uint64_t data2[200];
  __declspec(align(16)) uint64_t data3[200];
  __m128i* ptr = (__m128i*) data;
  __m128i* ptr2 = (__m128i*) data2;
  __m128i* ptr3 = (__m128i*) data3;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i, ++ptr, ++ptr2, ++ptr3)
    *ptr3 = _mm_and_si128(*ptr, *ptr2);
}
```

Comment: If you read this tutorial, it says that we can just cast, we don't have to load, why do you say we have to load the registers?

Comment: Which tutorial?

Comment: sorry, i thought I attached it here it is : https://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/cpp-getting-started-with-sse/

Comment: You are right, I just checked the generated assembly code. It turns out even the _mm_store_si128 isn't required because the compiler will generate it, see my updated answer.

Comment: If you don't align the data and leave the loading to the compiler it'll use unaligned access which is not good. Check the output assembly. Better load the data by hand and you might see the problem when you get a segfault.

Comment: _you might see the problem when you get a segfault._ ... or not. My compiler (msvc++) generates unaligned load/stores even if I explicitly use `_mm_load_si128` and `_mm_store_si128` for unaligned data.