# C++ SIMD: accumulate POPCOUNTs of uint64_t elements in an array

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I am trying to accumulate the `POPCOUNT`s for the `uint64_t` integers in an array using SSE instructions.
This is my code:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <nmmintrin.h>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{    
  uint64_t data[4] = {1,1,1,1};
  uint64_t data2[4] = {1,0,1,0};
  __m128i* ptr = (__m128i*) data;
  __m128i* ptr2 = (__m128i*) data2;

  int total = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i, ++ptr, ++ptr2)
    total += popcount(_mm_and_si128(*ptr, *ptr2)); // This doesn't work    
}
```

I need the equivalent of the `POPCOUNT` function which operates on the output of `_mm_and_si128`, so I can accumulate all the `POPCOUNT`s into the `total` variable.

Comment: Are you going to ask [one question per instruction](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42463284) :-) ?

Comment: @KerrekSB i felt like the two questions operate in their own space of specifics, and I didn't think it would help to lump them in together :)

Comment: Two links that may be very helpful for you are [SSSE3: fast popcount](http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html) and [Hand coded assembly beats intrinsics in speed and simplicity](http://danluu.com/assembly-intrinsics/). They both have been mentioned in a recent blog-post.

Comment: @zx485: no more SSSE3 link http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html

Comment: @IsaacPascual: Thx. New link at archive.org: [SSSE3: fast popcount](https://web.archive.org/web/20141228225919/http://wm.ite.pl/articles/sse-popcount.html)

Answer (score 3):

We have an entire research paper on this topic: [Faster Population Counts using AVX2 Instructions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.07612). Despite the title, it covers SSE as well. For a relevant software library, see [hamming_weight](https://github.com/CountOnes/hamming_weight). It includes all sorts of fast functions to do this type of work.

The short answer: you can use a Muła popcount function like so:

```
 __m128i popcount(__m128i v) {
    const __m128i lookup = _mm_setr_epi8(
    /* 0 */ 0, /* 1 */ 1, /* 2 */ 1, /* 3 */ 2,
    /* 4 */ 1, /* 5 */ 2, /* 6 */ 2, /* 7 */ 3,
    /* 8 */ 1, /* 9 */ 2, /* a */ 2, /* b */ 3,
    /* c */ 2, /* d */ 3, /* e */ 3, /* f */ 4
);
   __m128i low_mask = _mm_set1_epi8(0x0f);
   __m128i lo  = _mm_and_si128(v, low_mask);
   __m128i hi  = _mm_and_si128(_mm_srli_epi16(v, 4), low_mask);
   __m128i popcnt1 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lookup, lo);
   __m128i popcnt2 = _mm_shuffle_epi8(lookup, hi);
  return _mm_sad_epu8(_mm_add_epi8(popcnt1, popcnt2), _mm_setzero_si128());
}
```

The result from the `popcount` call is a 128-bit counter made of two 64-bit counters that you must add up. Summing up the two 64-bit counters can be done at the very end to save computational time.

Answer (score 1):

`POPCOUNT` doesn't work with SSE registers.  You'll need to save the result of `_mm_and_sil128` to memory, then use `POPCOUNT` (`_mm_popcnt_u64`) on the two halves since the `POPCOUNT` instruction is limited to at most a 64 bit operand.

Comment: Thanks, do you know what header file i should include so i can call `_mm_popcnt_u64`?

Comment: @Cauchy `#include "nmmintrin.h"`.  Complete reference to [Intel intrinsics](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/).

Comment: I'm getting an error `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/smmintrin.h: In function ‘__m128i _mm_mullo_epi32(__m128i, __m128i)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/smmintrin.h:328:22: error: ‘__v4su’ was not declared in this scope
   return (__m128i) ((__v4su)__X * (__v4su)__Y);
                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/include/smmintrin.h:328:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__X’
   return (__m128i) ((__v4su)__X * (__v4su)__Y);`

Comment: how exactly can I access the two halves?

Comment: @Cauchy I don't know about your compile error, as my mm headers don't use __v4su, but to access the two halves you can look at the definition of `__m128i` in `<emmintrin.h>`.  It's a union, with the two 64-bit halves accessible using `m128i_i64`.

Comment: The OP is using GCC which does not have `_mm_popcnt_u64`... use `__builtin_popcountll` instead.